# How to filter on optgroup based on multi selected input

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Let's say i have 1 collection select input and 1 grouped collection select as follow:

```
Input 1:
<select name="some_name_1" id="input_1_id">
   <option value="1"> Java Developer </option>
   <option value="2"> Ruby Developer </option>
   <option value="3"> C# Developer </option>
</select>

Input 2:
<optgroup label="Java Developer">
   <option value="1">Candidate A</option>
   <option value="2">Candidate B</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ruby Developer">
   <option value="3">Candidate C</option>
   <option value="4">Candidate D</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="C# Developer">
   <option value="5">Candidate E</option>
   <option value="6">Candidate F</option>
</optgroup>
```

What I would like to achieve is that the first input would allow user to select multiple options, and based on the options selected, the 2nd input will be filtered accordingly.

For example, let's say a user has selected both "Java Developer" and "Ruby Developer" in input 1. Then input 2 should display only

```
<optgroup label="Java Developer">
   <option value="1">Candidate A</option>
   <option value="2">Candidate B</option>
</optgroup>
<optgroup label="Ruby Developer">
  <option value="3">Candidate C</option>
  <option value="4">Candidate D</option>
</optgroup>
```

This is the simplified JQuery code that I have written so far:

```
  $(document).on("turbolinks:load", function () {

    input2_html = $('#input_2_id').html()
    $('#input_1_id').on('change', function(e){
        input1_text = $('#input_1_id :selected').text();
        options = $(input2_html).filter("optgroup[label='" + input1_text + "']").html();
        $('#input2_id').html(options).show();
    });
  })
```

The above code works if I select just a single option from input 1, and will not work if multiple options are selected. Appreciate if anyone could advise on how to handle this multi selected option case. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code will automatically show/hide `optgroup` elements inside `input_2_id` depending on the selected value(s) of `input_1_id`

It also resets the `value` of `input_2_id` when the value of `input_1_id` changes

```js
var $input1 = $('#input_1_id'),
  $input2 = $('#input_2_id'),

  $input2optgroups = $input2
  .find('optgroup');

$input1.change(function() {
    $input2optgroups
      .hide();

    $(this)
      .val()
      .map(function(id) {
        return $input1
          .find('option[value=' + id + ']')
          .text();
      })
      .forEach(function(text) {
        $input2optgroups
          .filter('[label="' + text + '"]')
          .show();
      });

    $input2
      .val(0);
  })
  .change();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select multiple name="some_name_1" id="input_1_id">
  <option value="1">Java Developer</option>
  <option value="2">Ruby Developer</option>
  <option value="3">C# Developer</option>
</select>

<select name="some_name_2" id="input_2_id">
  <option value="0">Select..</option>
  <optgroup label="Java Developer">
    <option value="1">Candidate A</option>
    <option value="2">Candidate B</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="Ruby Developer">
    <option value="3">Candidate C</option>
    <option value="4">Candidate D</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="C# Developer">
    <option value="5">Candidate E</option>
    <option value="6">Candidate F</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```